# Avoid the "You need to format the disk in drive F:" when plugging a TrueCrypt/VeraCrypt external drive

Tags: windows, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, encryption, truecrypt

When plugging a USB external hard drive encrypted with VeryCrypt, VeraCrypt detects it and asks for the password (this is expected, and works well thanks to the `Favorite Volumes > Mount selected volume when its host device gets connected` feature!)...

... but this message is also displayed: `You need for format the disk...`

[image]

The reason is obvious: the partition is unreadable for Windows, so Windows suggests to format it.

**Is there a way to avoid this message on each USB connection of the encrypted external hard drive?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did many tests, and finally one was working with VeraCrypt:

- Encrypt a non-system partition/drive > Standard VeraCrypt Volume > Select Device
- Then instead of clicking on **a partition, choose the disk**, e.g. `Harddisk 2`

This will encrypt the whole disk and not only a partition:

Benefits:

- No "unreabable disk for Windows" icon:

  [image]

  will be seen in Windows Explorer / Computer
- No *"You need to format the disk in drive ..."* will be displayed when plugging the USB hard drive

Drawback:

- The `Favorite Volumes > Mount selected volume when its host device gets connected` doesn't work anymore :(

  [image]

Comment: So you make the drive un-partitioned, with no MBR/GPT? Doesn't windows still ask to format it? A really empty disk would be un-partitioned too

Comment: @Xen2050 It doesn't ask to format it when you plug it. But it asks to re-intialize it (MBR) if you open the usual Windows `Disk Management` panel.